# Xamarin.Forms Page.DisplayAlert in Page.OnAppearing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, async-await, dialog

I am unable to get a `DisplayAlert` popup to show within the `OnAppearing` callback of a Xamarin.Forms `Page`.  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    this.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Consider yourself alerted", "OK");
}
```

Considering `DisplayAlert` is technically an `async` function, returning a `Task`, I have also tried the following:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await this.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Consider yourself alerted", "OK");
}
```

However, neither seem to work.  My guess is it doesn't really make much sense to make `OnAppearing` to be `async` at all, since it does not return a `Task`, and so this turns into a fire-and-forget situation with respect to the calling framework.  Same by extension goes for `DisplayAlert` in this context.  So on the one hand I don't really expect this to work at all, but in case I'm wrong, is it possible to use `DisplayAlert` in `OnAppearing`?

**Update**

Seems I failed to provide some context.  I'm working from an Xamarin.Forms Shell template; though I have already developed some past the initial template, so it's hard to say at this point to what extent the Shell itself contributes at all.  Also, my main target platform is Android.

That all being said, I was able to start a blank app template and try the above code in the otherwise fresh `MainPage` -- both worked fine.  I still do not know why they do not work in my actual application context, so I am going to do some digging there and report back any findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took my little experiment one step further and tried the basic Shell template app.

Adding the OP sample `DisplayAlert` code to the main `ItemsPage` codebehind did not work.  If I did this,

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
        viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);

    await this.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Consider yourself alerted", "OK");
}
```

the items would load but no dialog would show.  If instead I moved the dialog up,

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await this.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Consider yourself alerted", "OK");

    if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
        viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

the dialog would not show nor would the items load.  So the async execution died and/or wandered off into the great big bit bucket up in the sky.

I then tried adding the `DisplayAlert` sample to the main `AppShell` page, only to find the `OnAppearing` override does not get called at all for the `Shell` class.  This was confirmed by the following open Shell issue:  [[Bug] Shell - OnAppearing not executing
#6486](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin.forms/issues/6486#).

Finally, just as a final stretch, I tried hacking a call to `DisplayAlert` into the async callback executed by `LoadItemsCommand` in `ItemsPage.OnAppearing`.  A bit nasty since it's passing the view into the view-model, which is directly against good MVVM in the first place --

```
async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand(ItemsPage view)
{
    if (IsBusy)
        return;

    IsBusy = true;

    try
    {
        Items.Clear();
        var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }

        await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
            await view.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Consider yourself alerted", "OK"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Don't stone me.

This didn't seem to have any better results.  Just like when calling `DisplayAlert` directly in the page's `OnAppearing`, the execution just took a lunch break.  The spinner bound to the `IsBusy` flag never stopped, so that indicates the `finally` block never even got executed.

My general understanding at this point is that there is currently some limitation in the type of async operations that can be done from a Shell's `ContentPage`.  Even the `await`ed call to `DataStore.GetItemsAsync` is not truly asynchronous in this implementation, so I somewhat doubt it would actually work given a real, asynchronous database connection.  I have been able to get `DisplayAlert` working in the context of a normal event handler, so I think the issue is scoped to whatever initialization logic goes on during `OnAppearing` and whatever it ends up directly calling or scheduling.  Much of this is just observational speculation, but I may forward this on as a bug, unless someone can offer a more complete analysis.

**Update** (for closure, OCD, documentation, etc)

As the comments indicate, the version of Xamarin.Forms I was using (4.2.0) had a bug that has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: I just create a new project with shell template, then `add await this.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Consider yourself alerted", "OK");` in the `OnAppearing` method of `ItemsPage`, the alert do display on my side. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please also try to run the display alert code in Mainthread:`Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync...`.

Comment: Hey @JackHua-MSFT, thanks for getting back to me.  I'm afraid the only thing you're missing is that I happened to be running a few versions back on Xamarin.Forms (4.2.0) and .Essentials (1.2.0).  Tried this in a newer environment and it works as expected.  Sorry for the rookie mistake.

Comment: Ok, so the solution is use the latest Xamarin.forms!