# WhenAll Task.Run Tasks Hang when Exceptions Occur

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous, exception, xamarin.forms

I have a minimal example of some async code that is exhibiting strange behavior.  This is sandbox code, more geared at trying to understand async better --

```
private async Task ExhibitStrangeBehaviorAsync()
{
    async Task TaskA()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            throw new Exception(nameof(TaskA));
            await Task.Yield();
        });
    }

    async Task TaskB()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception(nameof(TaskB));
        });
    }

    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        TaskA(),
        TaskB(),
    };
    var tasksTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    try
    {
        await tasksTask;
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(tasksTask.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Intermittently, this code will hang.  I would like to better understand why.  My guess currently is the intermittent nature is due to the out-of-order execution of the aggregated tasks, and/or this line from [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async):

> Lambda expressions in LINQ use deferred execution, meaning code could end up executing at a time when you're not expecting it to.

`TaskA` would fall in this category.

The code does not seem to hang if `TaskB` also `Task.Run`s an async lambda, or if neither local `Task` function contains `Task.Run`, e.g.

```
    async Task TaskA()
    {
        //await Task.Run(async () =>
        //{
             throw new Exception(nameof(TaskA));
             await Task.Yield();
        //});
    }

    async Task TaskB()
    {
        //await Task.Run(() =>
        //{
            throw new Exception(nameof(TaskB));
        //});
    }
```

Can anybody shed some light on what's going on here?

**EDIT**

This is executing in the context of a UI thread, specifically that of a Xamarin.Forms application.

**EDIT 2**

Here is another variant on it that runs straight out of the Xamarin.Forms `OnAppearing` lifecycle method.  I had to modify `TaskA`/`B` slightly, though they break this way with the original setup above as well.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    async Task TaskA()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
            await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    async Task TaskB()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => throw new ArgumentException()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        TaskA(),
        TaskB(),
    };
    var tasksTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    try
    {
        await tasksTask;
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(tasksTask.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

There is some chance this may be related to [another issue I have had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431815/xamarin-forms-page-displayalert-in-page-onappearing) - I am using an older version of Xamarin.Forms, one which has problems with its `OnAppearing` handling async correctly.  I am going to try with a newer version to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: How are you running `ExhibitStrangeBehaviorAsync`? Is this a console or a WPF/WinForms app?

Comment: Works fine to me in the console. Where this code is used?

Comment: There's nothing in there that should hang, and I can't reproduce it in a console app either. I'm guessing you're using a `.Wait()` further up the chain and this is a GUI app? But a *complete* reproducer would be good, so we're not guessing. If you are calling `ExhibitStrangeBehaviorAsync().Wait()`, there's a race which could cause a deadlock

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're calling `ExhibitStrangeBehaviorAsync().Wait()` in a GUI app (or similar), as that's the only situation which I think of which can cause a deadlock here. This answer is written on that assumption.

The deadlock is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock), cause by the fact that you're running an `await` on a thread which has a `SynchronizationContext` installed on it, and then blocking that same thread higher up the callstack with a call to `.Wait()`.

When you run `TaskA()` and `TaskB()`, both of those methods post some work to the ThreadPool, which takes a variable amount of time. When the ThreadPool gets around to actually executing the `throw` statements, this causes the `Task` returned from `TaskA` / `TaskB` to complete with an exception.

`tasksTask` will complete when the two tasks returned from `TaskA` and `TaskB` complete.

The race comes from the fact that, at the point that this line is executed:

```
await tasksTask;
```

the task `tasksTask` may or may not have completed. `tasksTask` will have completed if the Tasks returned from `TaskA` and `TaskB` have completed, so it's a race against the main thread's progression towards the `await tasksTask` line, against how fast the ThreadPool can run both of those `throw` statements.

If `tasksTask` is completed, the `await` happens synchronously (it's smart enough to check whether the `Task` being awaited has already completed), and there's no chance of a deadlock. If `tasksTask` hasn't completed, then my guess is that you're hitting the deadlock described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock).

This is also consistent with your observation that removing the calls to `Task.Run` removes the deadlock. In this case, the tasks returned from `TaskA` and `TaskB` complete synchronously as well, so there's no race.

---

The morale of the story is, as is oft-repeated, do not mix async and sync code. Do not call `.Wait()` or `.Result` on a `Task` which is influenced in any way by `await`. Also consider tactical use of `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to guard against other people calling `.Wait()` on tasks which you produce.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup.  I would agree there is a race condition somewhere, and further tests have confirmed your diagnosis.  Calling `Task.Delay` for a substantial amount of time in async `TaskA` and async `TaskB` causes the deadlock, whereas before having both functions async did not hang.  However, I am not (directly, visibly) using .Wait.  I know `WhenAll` is not blocking, but is there a chance it `Wait`s internally? I would find that hard to believe.

Comment: I just repeated the `Task.Delay` test and it did not deadlock the second time.

Comment: That was what the above was intended to be.  But it's down in the guts of my app framework.  Trying to put something together that's just straight out of `OnAppearing` and I'm not getting so far.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: Yeah, something that we can run which reproduces the issue. If it only reproduces when bits of your application are present, then they're relevant to understanding what's happening

Comment: I have posted a simpler version that still intermittently deadlocks.  However, it seems this is 
just an issue with this version of Xamarin.Forms (4.2.0).  At any rate, I can't seem to reproduce it on a newer version.

Comment: OK. Take a look at the Threads window when it deadlocks. Double click each thread, see where it's stuck. Also put `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your awaits, see if that changes anything

Comment: After letting it sit and spin for awhile, I hit pause and looked at the threads window.  I had one hanging out in what looks like general Android OS code, and two sitting on `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw( Parameters)`, which I can only assume are from the exceptional tasks.

Comment: Adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` only adds the number of `Thread started: <Thread Pool>` messages in the Output log.  I am not very knowledgeable on how the thread pool works, but if it runs on a queue I wonder if the continuation is getting scheduled on a worker thread further down the queue that never gets executed?